# What is meant by the closure of a set in a scheme in this context?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

The context of this question is Hartshorne, Chapter II, Theorem 7.6. Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over a noetherian ring $A$, and $\mathscr{L}$ an invertible sheaf on $X$. The claim is that $\mathscr{L}$ is ample if and only if $\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m}$ is very ample over $\text{Spec }A$ for some $m > 0$.

For the forward direction, suppose $\mathscr{L}^{\otimes m}$ is very ample. Then there is an immersion $i X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_{A}^{n}$. Hartshorne then says to let $\overline{X}$ be the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}_{A}^{n}$.

What does this mean? Is this referring to the set theoretic closure, with the reduced induced subscheme structure? Or is it referring to the scheme theoretic closure, or something else?

Comment: Later in the proof you want to use results about projective schemes, so you want $\overline{X}$ to be a projective scheme, i.e. a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}_A^n$. Taking scheme theoretic closure gives you a closed subscheme, so that would work.

Comment: @AaronJohnson Thank you! I figured it could be inferred from context somehow but since I'm a relative beginner to this stuff I really wasn't sure.